# emacs projectile - initialize project cache without git, hg, etc. repository

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-projectile

I want setup the projectile project for project that has no local git, hg, bzr, etc. directories so I cannot use their repositories as source of project files. Is it enough to just create the `.projectile` file in the root directory and use the `C-u C-c p f` to refresh the cache. I've tried this and in my case it is not working (my `.projectile` is empty - shall I fill it with some rules?). What I would expect is the emacs/projectile to automatically index all my project, i.e. directory-by-directory, file-by-file, so I can make later quick search for the files.

Could you please give me some step-by-step hints ?

Thanks!

[--Update--]
This is an excerpt from my `.emacs` config file:

```
(require 'projectile)  
(projectile-global-mode)  
(setq projectile-indexing-method 'native)  
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)
```

After the `C-c p f` sequence I'm asked by the "Find file:" prompt but the only file in the list is the `.projectile` file itself - none of the project files are displayed.

Comment: What values you have for `projectile-enable-caching` and `projectile-indexing-method`?  The empty .projectile approach is valid.  What happens when you hit `C-c p f`?

Comment: @juanleon: I've updated the question above

Comment: Strange.  That setups works for me.  Does `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` or `projectile-globally-ignored-files` match the rest of the files?  What versions of Emacs/projectile are you using (I assume you are using Windows, because of the native indexing method)?

Comment: By the way, your .projectile is meant to remain empty; the cache is stored in a different place (file projectile.cache, on your ~/.emacs.d or similar)

Comment: None of the `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` directories or `projectile-globally-ignored-file` files match any of the files/directories in my project. The project includes mainly (~99,9%) `*.c`, `*.h` and Makefiles

Comment: I'm running the whole stuff on Win7. Emacs ver. 24.3.1, projectile ver. 0.10.0.

Comment: By saying that the setup works for you, you mean that:  
1) open the .projectile file in the projects' top-level dir  
2) `M-x projectile-find-file` and starts to type the beginning  of some filename from inside the project  
3) that filename is being expanded to the full filename  
4) you can open that file

Comment: Right.  I started with exact same configuration and versions than you ("emacs -q" + your lines) and `projectile-find-file` is working as usual (I can complete and open all files in project).  I use Linux, though.

Comment: When Emacs is filling the cache with new data? At the beginning of the `C-c p f` sequence?

Comment: Exactly, if the cache is empty (or you use C-u) and `projectile-enable-caching` is not nil.  You can check if the cache is empty by looking at projectile.cache file.

Answer (score 10):

Currently, I have found out that after you have created a `.projectile` file in the directory of your choice, projectile will only use it after you restart emacs from that directory.

The caching is working well.